# LWJGL - Hide cube face while hidden

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl, voxel

I have many problems unsolved, and i'm kind of new at LWJGL.

Here is a screen: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/07/1423885261-sans-titre.png

(this is 20x20x20 simple cube)

But as you can see, my fps are not bigger than 40 and every face of the cube is showing. How can i fix the fps drop and hide the hidden block behind another one ?

I have glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); and glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); but it only work INSIDE the block :x ...

Sorry for my english too but i really need help :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Culling**

If culling only works if you are inside a block your vertex winding order is most likely mixed up. If so you might want to change it from the default GL_CCW to  GL_CW or fix your vertex order to the default. [Reference here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling)

**SpeedUp**

For this your question has too few information. If you are not doing so already you might want to switch to using [Vertex_Buffer_Object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object). Preferably using a single geometry that is only translated.

An additional approach would be to only render objects that are in line of sight of the camera. One method for this is a [Binary Search Tree](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/bspfaq/index.html#9.txt)